# How much money did the participating nations spend in the Napoleonic Wars?

Tags: 19th-century, napoleonic-wars, money

How much money did Great Britain, Russia and France collect per year during Napoleonic wars as total revenue, and how much money did each one spend in total on that war?

Comment: Where have you looked so far, for this information?

Comment: The answer will not be simple - for significant portions of the period, France was engaged in rather creative finance. They created money, borrowed money against assets, devalued debts, fixed valuation against need rather than value, etc.  Great Britain pursued a policy of inflation and national debt. I'm less familiar with Russian finance, but I'm suspicious of the finances of any absolute monarchy.  The answer will not be a simple set of sums.

Comment: In addition, it will be difficult to separate spending _on the war_ from overall spending during the war. For example, is infrastructure spending (such as road building), which may have had an indirect benefit to fighting the war, to be included or not?

Comment: Hi Steve Bird,  I mean income from all sources. Just direct benefits I mean.

Answer (score 4):

I won't pretend that this is a comprehensive answer (or close to one) but I can offer some expenditure figures for Great Britain for the period 1803-1815.

These are taken from *The Foundations of British Maritime Ascendancy: Resources, Logistics and the State 1755-1815*, Roger Morriss (Cambridge UP, 2011) which in turn took them from *Abstract of British Historical Statistics*, Mitchell & Dean (Cambridge, 1962).

```
Year    Navy    Army    Civil   Debt    Total (£000,000)
1803    12.0    13.3    6.7     20.4    54.8
1804    8.1     15.5    5.1     20.7    53.0
1805    11.9    22.2    5.2     20.7    62.8
1806    14.3    25.8    5.2     22.3    71.4
1807    16.3    24.8    4.7     23.2    72.9
1808    16.9    24.0    5.3     23.8    73.3
1809    17.6    27.2    4.7     23.1    78.0
1810    19.4    28.9    5.2     24.2    81.5
1811    20.0    28.0    5.1     24.4    81.6
1812    19.6    33.8    5.2     24.6    87.3
1813    20.8    36.5    5.4     26.4    94.8
1814    22.5    49.6    5.3     27.3    111.1
1815    22.8    49.6    5.8     30.3    112.9

Total   222.2   379.2   68.9    311.4   1035.4
```

The figures are in Pounds Sterling and are gross government expenditure. The figure for the Army includes the Ordnance (and so includes some Navy expenditure). 'Civil' is civilian government expenditure while 'Debt' is the cost of servicing the country's debt.